# music21.stream.chordify() written to midi file is different from content in program

Tags: python, music21

When calling

```
chordifiedScore = score.chordify()
```

I can inspect chordifiedScore's content in the debugger. I see 11 chords in the first measure for example.

Then I write the score to a file with:

```
chordifiedScore.write('midi', './myscore.mid')
```

It works, I can open the midi file, but ...

... it has only one chord in the first measure. There are less chords than what I can see in the debugger. There are also chords missing in all the following measures.

Is this normal?

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: It shouldn't work that way.  Since it's not, best to discuss on the mailing list with a concrete example and then we can pub. the answer here to help others. But probably if my answer (as creator of music21) is "I have no idea" it might not work for anyone.

Comment: you might try again using v5 alpha 1 -- lots of chordify improvements that can get the tricky cases we missed before.